# why this function donnot generate random numbers?

Tags: c++, random, zeromq

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zhelpers.hpp>   

 void main(){
    char identity[10] = {};
    sprintf(identity, "%04X-%04X", within(0x10000), within(0x10000));
    printf("%s\n", identity);
}
```

I have taken reference from here:
https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/asyncsrv.cpp

Comment: What is `within()`? And please state observed behaviour, expected behaviour.

Comment: @DevSolar Perhaps its a function. I have given reference for the reviewrs.. in link

Comment: "Perhaps" that's your answer. You cannot just copy & paste code snippets from the web and expect them to work, especially not if you don't include the same headers and link the same libraries. And even then, you should *understand* the code first...

Comment: Actually I have added all files and still it generates same number. I do understand the code of zeromq and i am trying to implement that. Thats why I asked the question. I was stuck over there

Comment: The code you posted does not include any headers, and you do not state that you are linking with anything but the standard library. If you are linking with "zeromq" (whatever that is), state so, and tag your question accordingly. A direct link to the function used (or rather, its documentation) would also be helpful. As it stands, the above wouldn't even compile.

Comment: And if you expect somebody to dig through a github repository to find you your answer, that just doesn't fly here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Question is getting better. (Although now you're listing includes that you don't even use...) But still, you haven't answered my very first question: *What is `within()`?*

Comment: Look through the rest of the project to find out what `within` does (hint: it's in [one of the headers](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/zhelpers.hpp) included from this file). And please ask a clear question. It *does* generate random numbers (since that's what `within` does); why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @DevSolar Actually first I searched a lot about within but it does not refers to a function. But that example is from authentic source. from zeromq website itself. I dont know why it generates same number

Comment: Mike now has answered that first question in the meantime. Now, the second and third: What is the *observed* behaviour? What is the *expected* behaviour?

Comment: It generates 64F6-D716 everytime

Comment: @monsterrrrr: It uses `rand`, so that probably means the random number generator isn't being seeded. You'll need to call `srand` with a unique(ish) value each time the program starts; or better still use the C++11 `<random>` library as suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what `within()` does, but you may want to use the new methods to generate random numbers introduced with [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). The link has a nice example.

In case the link will become invalid in some future time, here's the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main {
    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    std::random_device rd;

    // Choose a random number between 1 and 6
    std::default_random_engine engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    int randomNumber = uniform_dist(engine);
    int anotherRandomNumber = uniform_dist(engine);
    std::cout << "Randomly-chosen number: " << randomNumber << '\n';
    std::cout << "Another Randomly-chosen number: " << anotherRandomNumber << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I hesitate to answer such a poor question...

Taking the definition of `within()` as found by Mike Seymour, your code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define within(num) (int) ((float) (num) * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))

void main(){
    char identity[10] = {};
    sprintf(identity, "%04X-%04X", within(0x10000), within(0x10000));
    printf("%s\n", identity);
}
```

This code *does* generate a (pseudo-) random number. What you are probably confused about is that it does generate **the same** (pseudo-) random number on each run of the program. However, that's what pseudo-random-number-generators **do**: Given the same seed (since you don't seed the generator via `srand()`), they generate the same sequence of numbers. (Hence "pseudo".)

I strongly recommend additional reading, like in [`man rand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand).